# how to import a Cmake Project which used .sh scripts for build to Vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

I have a legacy code base which has CMake configuration and .sh files which calls build commands with respect to build type ( release, relwithdebinfo etc.) as well as does a lot of things.

I have to work over codebase. So far I used STM32CubeIDe. I imported the project as existing Makefile project and then I changed C/C++ Build directory to where makefile outputs converted.

So whenever I did a change on the code, I hit the build command over UI and it calls make command at where I modifed the path above.
This is working but In case of a need of debug then I had to use .elf outputs and OZONE J link Debug program.
I have to do build+debug in same environment but eclipse is slow and making me struggle.
How can I make VSCode host to my legacy code in order to build and debug and also navigate in code i.e go to the definition of code in VSCode, not only building.

Please navigate me if anything needs to share from existing code base, if there is still unclear.

Comment: Do you have [the vscode-cmake-tools extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools) and the [vscode-cpptools](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools) extension installed? If you do, they don't need those .sh files.

Comment: .sh also build some software which written in go, also run protobuf things and secure software scripts written in python. I created a task which will run this .sh file and also created cpp_properties.json to include all required paths which is already builded by Cmake and trying to do debug with Cortex-Debug extension. I think this is okay ? @starball